# how to call javascript from dynamically created textbox in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, dynamic, textbox

```
 // Assign Context-Menu to Control
    $(function () {
        var txt1 = "#" + "<%= **myCal**.ClientID %>";

        // Attach Context-Menu to Control
        $(txt1).contextMenu(ctxtMenu, { theme: 'vista' });
    });
```

**Code behind**

```
            TextBox lbl = new TextBox ();
            lbl.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Double;
            lbl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.BlanchedAlmond;
            lbl.Text = eventname + "<br/>" + dt + "" + dt1;
            e.Cell.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

I want to use a dynamically created asp.net TextBox in place of myCal

what should i do? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a CSS class to this control:

```
lbl.CssClass = "menu";
```

and then use a class selector:

```
$(function () {
    // Attach Context-Menu to Control
    $('.menu').contextMenu(ctxtMenu, { theme: 'vista' });
});
```

Comment: one little problem it only gets called once when i try opening the context menu on right click the second time it doesnt work